django 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'userprofile' problem in related fileds
hi i have a django project and i have related database i can not reach for a two filed from database and  the above mistake appear and this is models.py for app display
class Display(models.Model) :
url=models.URLField(unique=True)
text = models.CharField(max_length=150) 

class  Display_Data(models.Model) :
     displays = models.ManyToManyField(Display,related_name='display_data')  
     users= models.ManyToManyField(User)
     choosenum=models.IntegerField()
     puplish_date =models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now) 

and this is models.py for app account
class UserProfile(models.Model):
user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
user_nickname=models.CharField(max_length=150)
userphoto =models.ImageField(upload_to='imageprofile/%Y/%m/%d/')



class UserUrl(models.Model):
  user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  url=models.URLField(default="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php? 
  id=100068020764035")

and this is views.py
def check_url_exists_and_person(url_to_check):

user_info_array = []

for i in range(1, 6):
    latest_successful_record = Display_Data.objects.filter(displays__url=url_to_check, 
    choosenum=i).order_by('-puplish_date').first()

    if latest_successful_record:
        user_info = {
            'user_nickname': 
  latest_successful_record.users.first().userprofile.user_nickname,
            'url': latest_successful_record.users.first().userurl.url
        }
    else:
        user_info = None

    user_info_array.append(user_info)

    return user_info_array


apparently latest_successful_record.users.first() is None.

latest_successful_record.users.first() probably returned None i.e. there is no related user to your Display_Data object.

thank you for intersetinjg i ommit firrst like this 'user_nickname': latest_successful_record.userprofile.user_nickname,
'url': latest_successful_record.userurl.url   but i still have error Display_Data' object has no attribute 'userprofile'
